# Read XML and map to a List<T> dataset using C#

Tags: c#, list, dataset

I have an existing `List<MyObject>` containing 15 MyObject(s). I want to read an XML document and map the XML document to this data.

The MyObject class has 3 public properties;

```
+id :int
+value1 :float
+value2 :float
```

The XML document has this structure;

```
  <root>

    <objects>
         <object id="1">
             <value1>S</value1>
             <value2>B</value2>
         </object>
         <object id="2">
             <value1>A</value1>
             <value2>J</value2>
         </object>
     </objects>
   </root>
```

Although the original `List<MyObject>` has 15 items, the incoming XML document only has 2 items, I need to maps the XML objects by id and change the List values.

so the data for  XML document

```
object id=1, value1 = s, value2= b
object id=2, value1 = a, value2= j
```

and the data for the `List<MyObject>` items are

```
object id=1 value1= a, value2 = b
object id=2 value1= c, value2 = d
object id=3 value1= k, value2 = z
object id=4 value1= y, value2 = e
```

I need to read the XML document and merge it with the existing `List<MyObject>`
the result of the list should look like;

```
object id=1 value1= s, value2 = b
object id=2 value1= a, value2 = j
object id=3 value1= k, value2 = z
object id=4 value1= y, value2 = e
```

Comment: it's hard to tell what you're asking here

Comment: I need to read the xml file, and map it to the List<MyObject> items to update the list items.

Comment: the items list has an id property, i need to read the id from the XML file and map value1 and value 2 properties to this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System.Xml;

...

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("filename.xml"); //or doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
XmlNodeList objects = doc.GetElementsByTagName("object"); //get list of objects from XML

List<object> myObjects = new List<object> { new object()}; //replace this with your List<object>

for (int i = 0; i < myObjects.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (XmlNode o in objects)
    {
        if (o.Attributes["id"].Value == myObjects[i].id.ToString())
        {
            myObjects[i].Value1 = o.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
            myObjects[i].Value2 = o.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do any kind of search and merge operation, I don't think a List is the most efficient data structure to use since most search operations are going to be of O(N) magnitude. Depending on the size of your dataset, that could be either bad or acceptable.

Secondly, I would override the Equals and GetHashCode methods in order allow for any kind of comparison and identify each object in the set to see if exists or not.

I think the List.Contains method internally invokes those methods in order to compare objects and see if an object exists or not in the list.

Having said that, I think the only approach would be to read the XML file in a separate collection, iterate over it, see if each objects exists in the original collection you have, and replace it if it does.

A LINQ query might simplify the implementation as well.

Comment: I didnt like the List<T> implementation here either, its an exiting app so Im stuck with the data structure ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with linq your main map here is id since the id is the same you already know based on your example your xml and your list it could be something like this

```
List<MyObject> myobjectlist = new List<MyObject>();
```

then i would select all the values from list whe object id is 1

```
MyObject firstobject=(from c in myobjectlist where c.id=1 selec c).FirstOrDefault();
```

your xml query might be somethink like this

```
var query = from node in results.Descendants("objects") 
            where node.Attribute("id").Value == "1"
            select
            {
                value1 = node.Element("value1").Value,
                value2 = node.Element("value2").Value
            };
```

the next step is to map it

```
firstobject.value1=query.value1;
firstobject.value2=query.value2;
```

and do the same with an object that has id 1